# sbt global plugins fail to load sometimes

Tags: sbt

I'm having problems with global plugins every once in a while, especially when I checkout another branch of my project from git. I installed sbt-dependency-graph as per their readme as a global plugin. global.sbt has a line

```
net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings
```

and I am getting this annoying `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/virtualvoid/sbt/graph/Plugin$` error even when I just run sbt in my project root. We also have a global plugin in a form of scala file in ~/.sbt/0.13, sometimes it causes problems as well. I haven't picked up the pattern yet.

Answer (score 1):

you should install the sbt-dependency-graph plugin

#### step 1:

- vim ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt
- input:

addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.7.5")

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")

#### step 2:

- vim ~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt
- input:

net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings

now you can use dependency-graph:

***sbt dependency-graph***

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, and the cause was the project I had open depended on a newer and incompatible version of sbt-dependency-graph. SBT decided to put the newer on in the classpath, and so the line in my global.sbt file didn't work anymore.